# Show that the $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ does not exist by $\varepsilon - \delta$ definition.

Tags: calculus, epsilon-delta

Let $f(x)$ be

$f(x) =
\begin{cases} 
     \space\space\space 0 & \text{if } x \text{ is rational}\\
    \space\space\space1 & \text{if } x \text{ is irrational}
\end{cases}$

Prove that $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$ does not exist.

$\forall \varepsilon \gt 0$ $\exists \delta \gt 0$ s.t
$0 \lt |x - 0| \lt \delta$ $\implies$ $|f(x) - L| \lt \varepsilon$

I tried using contradiction.

Set $\varepsilon \lt \frac 12$. By definition, for any given $\varepsilon$ there exists a $\delta$ such that everything is satisfied, so if I show that there's is not such $\delta$ for a specific $\varepsilon$ the proof is done.

First case: let $x$ approach $0$ from rationals numbers. What I mean is that $x$ is approaching $0$ but "ignoring" any irrational number in the way.

$0 \lt |x| \lt \delta$ $\implies$ $|0 - L| \lt \frac 12$

$|0 - L| = |-L| = |L| \lt \frac 12\iff -\frac 12 \lt L \lt \frac 12$

Second case: let $x$ approach $0$ from irrational numbers, ignoring any rational number in the way.

$0 \lt |x| \lt \delta$ $\implies$ $|1 - L| \lt \frac 12$

$|1 - L| \lt \frac 12 \iff -\frac 12 \lt 1 - L \lt \frac 12 \iff \frac 12 \lt L \lt \frac 32$

There it is. From the first inequality $L \lt \frac 12$, but the second tells that $L \gt \frac 12$. Contradiction. There is no such $\delta$ because $L$ is not a fixed number. Is this valid?

Comment: "such that everything is satisfied" - Be specific instead of using vague (or rather too general) words like "everything".

Comment: "let $x$ approach $0$ from rationals numbers" - in the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ formalism there is no such thing as "approach".

Comment: How could I prove it?

Comment: Your idea is correct. It's how you write it that could be better. Do you have any example from your teacher that you could look at?

Comment: I'm actually studying by myself, so I don't have anyone to ask but people in this website.

Comment: Okay... I just posted a proof. Others are also welcome to post proofs to show alternative ways of writing them, and to comment on mine if they think that something could be done in a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof by contradiction:

Assume that the limit exists and equals $L.$ Take $\epsilon=\frac13$ and let $\delta>0$ be such that $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ whenever $0<|x-0|<\delta.$

Since the rationals are dense in $\mathbb R$ there is $x_{\text{rational}}\in(-\delta,\delta)\cap\mathbb Q.$ Then $0<|x_{\text{rational}}-0|<\delta$ so we shall have $|f(x_{\text{rational}})-L|<\epsilon,$ i.e. $|0-L|<\frac13.$ This implies that $-\frac13<L<\frac13.$

Likewise, since the irrationals are dense in $\mathbb R$ there is $x_{\text{irrational}}\in(-\delta,\delta)\cap(\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q),$ and $0<|x_{\text{irrational}}-0|<\delta$ so we shall have $|f(x_{\text{irrational}})-L|<\epsilon,$ i.e. $|1-L|<\frac13,$ which implies that $\frac23<L<\frac43.$

Thus, $-\frac13<L<\frac13$ and $\frac23<L<\frac43.$ But these two conditions are incompatible. Contradiction!

We can therefore conclude that the limit does not exist.

Comment: Notice that I pick *one* rational $x$ and *one* irrational $x$. We don't have to deal with all of them. Also I explain why we can pick such numbers: because both subsets are dense in the interval.

Comment: I wasn't familiar with rationals and irrationals being dense in $\mathbb R$, that's something new to me. Could you explain why the interval $(-\delta, \delta)$?

Comment: I suppose that you mean that you hadn't heard the word "dense" in this meaning before. You seem to know it anyways.

Comment: The interval $(-\delta,\delta)$ is the interval on which $|x-0|<\delta.$

Comment: Oh, wonderful! Thank you!

Comment: I took $\epsilon=\frac13$ to really make the two intervals clearly separated. Taking $\epsilon=\frac12$ also works but then the two intervals touch, making the incompatibility a little less clear.